# Standalone assembly contract: control flow error

Tags: evm, assembly

I'm trying to understand why the following toy contract does not work. I can deploy it successfully, and transactions with fewer than 36 bytes of data are successful, but those containing 36 bytes or more fail. I would expect that no failures would exist for any input size.

```
{
  codecopy(0x0, 0x0, codesize())
  return(0xD, sub(codesize(), 0xD))

  if lt(calldatasize(), 0x24) {
    stop
  }

  if lt(calldatasize(), 0x84) {
    stop
  }

  stop
}
```

Bytecode: `386000600039600d3803600df36024361015601657005b6084361015602057005b00`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in your deployed/run-time byte code the jump destinations are wrong. I don't think the assembler is expecting to find a constructor in there, and so it doesn't account for the 13 byte shift in the jump destinations.

This is the run-time dissasembly. You can see that the jumps are 0xd off.

```
0000  PUSH1 0x24
0002  CALLDATASIZE
0003  LT
0004  ISZERO
0005  PUSH1 0x16  <-- should be 0x09
0007  JUMPI

0008  STOP

0009  JUMPDEST
000a  PUSH1 0x84
000c  CALLDATASIZE
000d  LT
000e  ISZERO
000f  PUSH1 0x20  <-- should be 0x13
0011  JUMPI

0012  STOP

0013  JUMPDEST
0014  STOP
```

If you want to explore this kind of thing, I recommend LLL. The LLL compiler is available when you build Solidity from source. The LLL equivalent of your contract is as follows:

```
(returnlll
  (seq
    (when (lt (calldatasize) 0x24) (stop))
    (when (lt (calldatasize) 0x84) (stop))
    (stop)))
```

The `returnlll` expression above is a macro that takes into account the constructor/deployment code when invoking the compiler, so this problem does not occur.

You can find LLL documentation [here](http://lll-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).